# Eсть ли более питоновский способ вывести квадрат из нулей с единицами по диагоналям?

Tags: python, циклы

```
size = int(input())
row = [0 for i in range(size)]
for i in range(len(row)):
    row[i], row[-i-1] = 1, 1
    row_t = ' '.join(str(k) for k in row)
    print(row_t)
    row[i], row[-i-1] = 0, 0
```

Comment: _квадрат из нулей с одиницами по диагоналях_?Что это?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, по примеру понятно что это...

Comment: 1 0 0 0 1/n
0 1 0 1 0/n
0 0 1 0 0/n
0 1 0 1 0/n
1 0 0 0 1

Comment: по-моему, вполне себе нормальное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, например:

```
import numpy as np

size = 10
matrix = np.zeros((size, size), int)
np.fill_diagonal(matrix, 1)
np.fill_diagonal(np.fliplr(matrix), 1)
print(matrix)
```

Вывод:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```